# finding a unique set of strings that are unordered

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have some data like so:

```
> dput(test1)
structure(list(User = c(95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 
113L, 113L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 
135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 
135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 
135L, 135L, 135L), Daypart6 = c("Afternoon", "Dinner", "Breakfast", 
"Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Breakfast", "Dinner", 
"Lunch", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Breakfast", "Breakfast", "Breakfast", 
"Breakfast", "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Breakfast", "Lunch", 
"Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", 
"Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", 
"Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", 
"Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", 
"Dinner", "Dinner", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", 
"Lunch", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Dinner", 
"Dinner", "Dinner", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Lunch", 
"Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", 
"Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Dinner", 
"Dinner", "Dinner", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Evening", "Dinner", 
"Evening", "Dinner", "Evening", "Dinner", "Evening", "Evening", 
"Dinner", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Dinner", "Evening", "Evening", 
"Evening", "Dinner")), .Names = c("Code", "TimeOfDay"), sorted = "User", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2d98fd8>)
>

library(data.table)
test[,uniqueTOD:=paste(unique(TimeOfDay),collapse='/'),'Code']
```

I get things back that are really the same like:

```
 Breakfast/Dinner
Dinner/Breakfast
```

In python there is a way of making an unordered unique set using the set. Is there anything like that in R?

Note: this is a subset of the data so it might not have the unique combination both ways like described. the data is merely for structure purposes.

Comment: You can just include a `sort` - `test[,uniqueTOD:=paste(sort(unique(TimeOfDay)),collapse='/'),'Code']`

Comment: @AndrewGustar perfect. Forgot about sort. Thanks!